# How to get customer first name and last name from billing address?

Tags: magento-1.9, billing-address

I am using below code to get customer firstname and lastname from billing address but it is not returning any value. Can someone please help how we can get those information from billing address. Any help will be great.

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId('700590221');
$billingAddress     = $order->getBillingAddress();
echo 'FirstName: ' . $billingAddress->getFirstName() . PHP_EOL;
echo 'LastName: ' . $billingAddress->getLastName();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few issue may be in your code,

**getFirstName()** should be **getFirstname()** as at db table field name is firstname.***getFirstName*** indicated at the filed name is **first_name** and that is **wrong**

and **getLastName()** should be `getLastname()` as at db table field name is  **lastname()**.***getLastName*** indicated at the filed name is **last_name** and that is **wrong**

Also you check the order **700590221**  exists  at system*.

For first case, you can check availability  by  `$order->getId()` give ***numeric value if order exits at system*** else **give value `false`**

### Code

```
<?php
  $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId('700590221');
  if($order && $order->getId()) {
      $billingAddress     = $order->getBillingAddress();
      echo 'First Name: ' . $billingAddress->getFirstname().PHP_EOL;
     echo 'Last Name: ' . $billingAddress->getLastname();
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace your code with this :

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId('700590221');
    $billingAddress     = $order->getBillingAddress();
    echo 'FirstName: ' . $billingAddress->getFirstname() . PHP_EOL;
    echo 'LastName: ' . $billingAddress->getLastname();
```